# How to get data in INT from SQLDataReader in .NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldatareader

I am trying to get `int` value from the database but It is throwing an error

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte' to type 'System.Int32'.

In the database, Active field is `tinyint`.

Also, how to return both values from this method.

```
private string CheckData(string firstValue, string SecondValue, int Active)
{
    string Data = "";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    string query = @"select M.ident Mi, mmp.active Active 
                     from Iden.Iden M
                     inner join PtM.MPt MMP on MMP.mPat = M.id
                     where M.ident = 'firstValue' 
                       and Mi.ident = 'SecondValue'";
    sb.Append(query);

    sb.Replace("firstValue", firstValue);
    sb.Replace("SecondValue", SecondValue);
            
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString());
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = connection;

    try
    {
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Data = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Mi"));
                Active = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("Active"));
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _log.Error($"Exception:{ex.Message}");
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
        connection.Dispose();
    }

    return Data;
}
```

Comment: It's a `TINY_INT` not an `INT`.  A tiny int maps to a `byte` in .NET code. The reader reads it as an object, which means that the actually representation will be as a _boxed_ byte.  You can only unbox boxed values to their actual type.  If you want to represent it as an integer in your code, you will need to unbox it to a `byte` first and then cast the byte to an `int`: `Active = (int) reader.GetByte(reader.GetOrdinal("Active"));`

Comment: Two more comments.  1) Your code has SQL Injection issues, use parameters rather than `StringBuilder.Replace`, and 2) since you are fishing out the ordinal values, do it once (before going into the `while` loop) rather than doing on each pass through the loop.  Your code may end up noticeably faster (if you have enough rows): `var dataOrdinal = reader.GetOrdinal("Mi");` and similar for `activeOrdinal`.  Then using them in the GetXxx methods.

Comment: How is the `Active` column declared in your SQL Schema.  Is it a `Bit`?  If so, consider making `Active` a `bool` in your C# code and using `reader.GetBool()`.  Oh, and you should dispose your data reader.  Read up on using the `using` keyword for disposing IDisposable objects

Comment: @Flydog57, Thanks. How to return both `Data` and `Active`. Also, how to get the `boolean` if I do not want to use `int`.

Comment: Hi @Flydog57, it is `tinyint` in the SQL schema. Could you please provide me proper solution for this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a stab at it.  I can't debug it (since I don't feel like creating a database).

First I create a type to hold the results.  You could just use a Tuple, but this seems clearer:

```
public class DataActive
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public byte Active { get; set; }
}
```

I make your function return a collection of these - it's not obvious from your code that there is only one.

You'll also notice that I use `SqlParameter`s to add `firstValue` and `secondValue` to your query.  Look up *SQL Injection* (and *Little Bobby Tables*).

If you are using a recent version of C# (which I don't), there's a new syntax for `using` that requires less indenting.  The `using` statements stick a call to `Dispose` in a finally statement at the end of the block.  Also note that I'm disposing the SqlCommand and the DataReader

```
public static IEnumerable<DataActive> CheckData(string firstValue, string secondValue)
{
    var results = new List<DataActive>();

    const string query = @"select M.ident Mi,mmp.active Active from Iden.Iden M
                Inner join PtM.MPt MMP on MMP.mPat =M.id                    
                where M.ident = @firstValue and Mi.ident = @secondValue";

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
        {
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = connection;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@firstValue", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = firstValue;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@secondValue", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = secondValue;

            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    var dataOrdinal = reader.GetOrdinal("Mi");
                    var activeOrdinal = reader.GetOrdinal("Active");
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            results.Add(new DataActive
                            {
                                Data = reader.GetString(dataOrdinal),
                                Active = reader.GetByte(activeOrdinal),
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _log.Error($"Exception:{ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

If your TINY_INT `Active` represents a boolean value, figure out what the rule is, and do a conversion *after* you get the value using `reader.GetByte`.

One final note, it's often better to log `ex.ToString()` rather than `ex.Message`.  You get the message and the stack that way.